# What sort of transistor is this?

Tags: identification, bjt

I come back to ask for the help of the community in order to identify a device which was  given to me several years ago by an electronics component dealer. This time I know something more, precisely

- it seems a PNP transistor since it appears as a two junction device with a common terminal which leads to a N-doped regions (it may be a double diode, but in this case it would be extremely uncommon device),
- the (gold plated) base terminal is the center one (see pictures below),
- the (gold plated) body, including the mounting screw, is isolated from the terminals
- the producer is ST Microelectronics (i.e. SGS-Thomson) (see pictures below),
- the body is marked with the following alphanumerical codes: **520400501C** and **8828** (between these codes lies the ***ST*** logo) (again, see pictures below).

**What I'd like to know**: a data sheet would be perfect (as usual) but even a summary of the basic characteristics will suffice.

For explanation and completeness I add the following pictures of the device.

[image]  [image]

[image]  [image]

Comment: Maybe an SCR. What makes you call one electrode "base"

Comment: Try tracing characteristics ... It would not be too difficult.

Comment: @Andyaka I used the junction tester function of one of my digital multimeter and measured a junction voltage of \$(0.614\div 0.615)\mathrm{V}\$ respect to each of the other terminals. The highly symmetrical voltage made also me suspicious about the nature of the device. Moreover the case is isolated from other terminals, no matter the polarity of the voltage I use to check conductivity.

Comment: @Antonio51 this is a good idea and I'll surely do, as this leads to an identification of the other terminals (hopefully... if this is not a symmetrical device).

Comment: There seem to be several people on the internet who think it's a 2N5005, but I can't find anything about it on the ST web site.

Comment: Very Interesting observation @SimonB: did you make your guess by searching for the case or di you worked on other details?

Comment: here is the link for 2N5005 https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/6080-lds-0237-datasheet  
2N5005
https://www.microsemi.com/existing-parts/parts/45458
This high speed transistor is rated at 5 amps and is military qualified up to a JANTXV level.  This TO-59 isolated package is available with a 180 degree lead orientation.

Comment: 8828 is the date code, the 28th week (mid-July) of 1988.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I googled for 520400501C, and found an ebay listing which also called it a 2N5055, and also several pictures using image search that also contained 2N5005 in them.  The pictures seem to match.  But that doesn't prove it's a compatible transistor inside the case!

Comment:  @SimonB... I did the same google search several times during the years and wasn't able to found nothing. What a luck!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Fellows, thank you all very much. I accepted the answer by @SpehroPefhany but I you all would deserve a thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be really old since ST isn't that old.  Mid to late 1980s at the earliest. You can look up when SGS and Thomson got together. Perhaps 1988 is the year of manufacture.

So probably silicon (you can tell from the diode voltage and also identify collector from emitter if it's a BJT- the symmetry and voltage you measure point towards it being silicon diodes).

You can measure the gain if it's a BJT with many multimeters- using the hFE function. If there is no gain, then it's a dual diode.

This kind of case was typically used with thyristors, however they generally had only two lugs and the case was the third connection. If it's a transistor it would not be suprising if the case is also connected to the collector.

Might be some house numbered device for some military or space application- literally a gold-plated design.

2N5005 seems like a plausible part number. There is a listing [here](https://www.radio741.com/39194-2n5005-st-silicon-npn-power-transistor-520400501c.html) for an identically marked part which the seller claims is a 2N5005:

[image]